# How to add a backend with virtual machine IP for Azure Load Balancer in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-load-balancer

I am creating an Azure load balancer that I need to route the incoming traffic to backend pool which consist of a virtual machine.

I am using Terraform to do this.

So far, I have created the followings:

1. Load Balancer
2. Load Balancer Rule
3. Backend Address Pool
4. A health probe

But in the `terraform` for backend, there's no way I can setup the IP address of the VM.

Here's my code. How can I do this?

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "TestLoadBalancer"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "classiclb"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.vm.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "example" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name            = "classiclb"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "example" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                = "classiclb"
  port                = 80
  interval_in_seconds = 10
  number_of_probes    = 3
  protocol            = "Http"
  request_path        = "/"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "example" {
  resource_group_name            = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                           = "classiclb"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "classiclb"
  backend_address_pool_id        = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
  probe_id                       = azurerm_lb_probe.example.id
}
```

Comment: Don't you need to use [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb_backend_address_pool_address) as well for that?

Comment: Hey exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Hey I get the error: `Invalid resource type
│
│   on 12-lb.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "example":
│   43: resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "example" {
│
│ The provider hashicorp/azurerm does not support resource type "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address".`

Comment: This seems to be a new issue, maybe you are using old version of the provider?. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for your original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments, the addresses are added using [azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/lb_backend_address_pool_address).

Comment: Hi I am getting the error `The provider hashicorp/azurerm does not support resource type
│ "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address".`

Comment: By upgrading the provider to the newest version (`2.67.0`) fixed this. Thank you!

Comment: how did you able to find this resource? I searched literally everywhere but couldn't find it.

Comment: @JananathBanuka Its listed in azurem docs. Maybe you look at old version of docs as well?

Comment: Excuse me but that does not seem to reference a VM either. The documentation for `ip_address` says “The Static IP Address which should be *allocated to this Backend Address Pool*”, and it's *optional*. It also says it can only be added to sku=Standard LB, but sku=Basic LBs are supposed to work, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct way to add a network interface into the backend address pool is using [network_interface_backend_address_pool_association](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/network_interface_backend_address_pool_association).